# In MPI, what is non-blocking I/O used for?

Tags: c++, io, mpi, nonblocking

What I assumed: non-blocking I/O is used to leverage the gap between data loading and computation.
In another word, while loading the data, we can do some computations at the same time.
Accordingly, the following program

```
MPI_File_read_at_all_begin(...);
... // do some computations
MPI_File_read_at_all_end(...);
```

should perform better than

```
MPI_File_read_at_all(...);
... // the same computations of the previous program
```

However, I didn't witness the expected result.
Why? Did I misunderstand？

Comment: We have no idea what you "witnessed".  Where is the code?  Where is the input?  How complex are the calculations?  What is the hardware configuration?  What are the compiler settings?  Where are the measurements?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. This is the nature, but need an additional thread to read file.

Comment: you implicitly assumed your MPI library features a progress thread. The MPI standard does **not** mandate such a thing, so all I/O being performed at `MPI_File_read_at_all_end()` time is a valid behavior w.r.t the MPI standard.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by something like

```
{ // run with a thread
    MPI_File_read_at_all_begin(...);
    MPI_File_read_at_all_end(...);
}
... // do some computations
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking I/O or communication is used for efficiency. The problem with blocking calls is that you need to wait till the operation has completed. With non-blocking calls, you can issue some request (send, write, read,..) and test or wait later for the completion of the request (MPI_WAIT, MPI_TESt, MPI_WAITALL,..). Having said that, nonblocking operations usually start with an 'i' e.g. MPI_File_**i**write_.. or MPI_File_**i**read_..

Having said that, non-blocking are not always more effective. If you have a long computation phase, non-blocking operations are great as they can be hidden behind the computational phase (e.g checkpointing). However, you need to make sure that the buffer used (e.g. for writing data to the disk) is not changed inside the computational phase until the writing operation compelets.

Looking into your code, you can see that you are using an blocking I/O operation. You function is described [here](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_File_read_at_all_begin.html)

Take a look at the [Manual](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.0/mpi40-report.pdf#page=290&zoom=100,120,142) at Section 6.12. There you can see how to use non-blocking collective MPI calls. Note that:

> "Unlike point-to-point operations, nonblocking collective operations
> do not match with blocking collective operations,.."